# Issues with installing "terra" package in R Studio on Windows 11

Tags: r, installation, terra

I'm using R Studio Version:

> RStudio 2022.02.3+492 "Prairie Trillium" Release
> (1db809b8323ba0a87c148d16eb84efe39a8e7785, 2022-05-20) for Windows
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

on Windows 11, with Rtools42 (rtools42-5355-5357) installed (as specified by the package developer). I also have terra's dependency Rcpp installed without problems. However I cannot get terra to install properly, I keep on getting this message:

```
> install.packages("terra", lib="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library")
```

> There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
> binary source needs_compilation
> terra  1.2-5 1.7-39              TRUE
>
> installing the source package ‘terra’
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/terra_1.7-39.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 815403 bytes (796 KB)
> downloaded 796 KB
>
> installing *source* package 'terra' ...
> package 'terra' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> using staged installation
>
> ---
>
> WARNING: this package has a configure script
> It probably needs manual configuration
>
> ---
>
> libs
>
> arch - i386
> Error in .shlib_internal(args) :
> C++17 standard requested but CXX17 is not defined
> removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library/terra'
> restoring previous 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library/terra'
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘terra’ had non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
> ‘C:\Users\ITU\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMXWK42\downloaded_packages’

When I try to install the package as specified on the GitHub page of the developer using:

```
Sys.setenv("R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS" = "true")
remotes::install_github("rspatial/terra")
```

I get this similar response:

> Downloading GitHub repo rspatial/terra@HEAD
> checking for file 'C:\Users\ITU\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMXWK42\remotesa9e45faa574b\rspatial-terra-78ae185/DESCRIPTION' ...
> preparing 'terra': (465ms)
> checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
> cleaning src
> checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (1.2s)
> checking for empty or unneeded directories
> building 'terra_1.7-42.tar.gz'
> Warning: file 'terra/cleanup' did not have execute permissions: corrected
> Warning: file 'terra/configure' did not have execute permissions: corrected
>
> Installing package into ‘D:/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> installing *source* package 'terra' ...
> using staged installation
>
> ---
>
> WARNING: this package has a configure script
> It probably needs manual configuration
>
> ---
>
> libs
>
> arch - i386
> Error in .shlib_internal(args) :
> C++17 standard requested but CXX17 is not defined
> removing 'D:/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/terra'
> Warning message:
> In i.p(...) :
> installation of package ‘C:/Users/ITU/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpMXWK42/filea9e42194bbd/terra_1.7-42.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Has anyone else had the similar problem recently and managed to solve it?

I tried also tried re: and [older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72670450/having-trouble-installing-terra-package) StackOverflow suggestion:

```
install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')
```

to see if it would work, but I get the same compiler compatibility error:

> Installing package into ‘D:/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’ (as ‘lib’ is
> unspecified) Package which is only available in source form, and may
> need compilation of   C/C++/Fortran: ‘terra’ installing the source
> package ‘terra’
>
> trying URL
> 'https://rspatial.r-universe.dev/src/contrib/terra_1.7-42.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1794771 bytes (1.7 MB)
> downloaded 1.7 MB
>
> - installing *source* package 'terra' ...
>   ** using staged installation
>
>   **********************************************    WARNING: this
>   package has a configure script
>   It probably needs manual configuration    **********************************************
>
> ** libs
>
> *** arch - i386 Error in .shlib_internal(args) :    C++17 standard requested but CXX17 is not defined
>
> - removing 'D:/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/terra' Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘terra’ had non-zero exit
>   status

Answer (score 1):

The RStudio version is almost completely irrelevant. You need to [update R to the newest version](https://cran.r-project.org/) and you need to install [Rtools43](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/rtools.html) (or later versions in the future).